# To add find_by_ to a model for a virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User model and I have following in the User model

```
def name
  last_name.blank? ? first_name : "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

How can I add a find_by_name function to the User model so that I can do this:

```
User.find_by_name("Peter Smith")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that using `named_scope`

Jim and NAD answers for this similar question [Rails virtual attribute search or sql combined column search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806394/rails-virtual-attribute-search-or-sql-combined-column-search) are probably a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Split the name into two parts, first_name and last_name and search them

```
named_scope :find_by_name, lambda {|name|   {:conditions => ["first LIKE '%?%' or last LIKE'%?%'", name.split(' ').first, name.split(' ').last]}}
```

Comment: why are you using LIKE here...why cant you use like this `named_scope :find_by_name, lambda {|name|   {:conditions => ["first_name = ? or last_name = ?", name.split(' ').first, name.split(' ').last]}}
`

Comment: I get it..if the last name contains middle name also, we will miss the record if we directly compare...

Answer (score 0):

`attr_acessible :name` Makes `name` like a regular instance variable, which can be accessed plainly as `name` or with `self.name`. Now, I guess you can do User.find_by_name('somename');